# Плагин jqte - встраиваемый редактор Jquery

Tags: jquery, плагин, javascript

Ссылка на доки:
[link text](http://jqueryte.com/documentation)

К сожалению, в документации не нашел, как сказать плагину работать с возвращенным от Ajax контентом. Чтобы текстовые поля были преобразованы в редактор.
Со статическим контентом работает, а вот с динамическим...
Может кто знает обходные пути решения? Другой плагин не хочется ставить

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[.jqteVal()](http://jqueryte.com/documentation#method-jqteVal)

> This method using for **changing to the value** of the editor.

Comment: Это свойство задает текст внутри редактора, но никак не включает его

Comment: что значит "включает" ? `.jqte();` ? просто вызывайте этот метод на полученное поле в success handler.